# Replace string in a text document in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a text file called "delete.txt".
The content is

```
My name is "David", "David"
```

I want to replace the second "David" with "Hello". I can only replace both of them with this:

```
$David = Get-Content -path C:\Users\David\Documents\delete.txt 
$David -replace "David", "Hello" | Out-File C:\Users\David\Documents\delete.txt
```

There could be more "David"'s in the file but I just want to replace the second one.

Comment: So you might look for the comma in front of the "David" as well. Or you search for "David" followed by the end of the line. It depends how your input file looks.

Comment: @Olaf. Thansk this way of thinking actually solves my problem :-) But just out of curiosity is there a way to find the position of the start of the two "David"s

Comment: Of course ... take a look at the cmdlet [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
$David -replace '"David", "David"','"David", "Hello"' | Out-File C:\Users\David\Documents\delete.txt
```

Comment: This works too, thanks. The comment from from Olaf works too... Also your answer from yesterday has helped me a lot, especially the trick with parentheses